# How to convert from std::vector<float> to std::istream?

Tags: c++, istream

I have an std::vector and the function expects an std::istream:

```
callMe(std::istream& is)
```

What is the best way to do the conversion? Is there something more clever than?

```
std::stringstream sstr;
for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i) {
    sstr << myVector[i] << " ";
}
std::istringstream istr{sstr.str()};
callMe(istr);
```

**EDIT:** Thanks for the suggestions so far! *Updated* code:

```
std::stringstream sstr;
for(const float& val : myVector) {
    sstr << val << " ";
}
callMe(sstr);
```

Comment: Shouldn't be a need for `std::istringstream istr{sstr.str()};`. `std::stringstream` [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `std::istream`. Probably have to rewind the stream, though.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i)` is a good place for a range-based for. `for(const auto & val: myVector.size() { sstr << val << " "; }` Could also use `for_each` from <algorithm>, but I don't think it would be any faster or clearer.

Comment: It is really hard to answer this without knowing why `callMe()` takes an `istream` to begin with, and how it actually reads values from that `istream` (formatted reads vs binary reads). Converting the `vector` to a `string` wrapped in an `(i)stringstream` *may or may not* work properly. We need more details about what `callMe()` actually expects for input, before this can be answered definitively.

Comment: You might like to try to fix it so that you don't have an unnecessary space after the last element.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: `callMe()` extracts the values again using operator>>, e.g. `float a0, a1, a2; is >> a0 >> a1 >> a2;`. However, the number of values (a0, a1, ...) may vary.

Comment: @RichardKeil OK, then formatting the `vector` into a space-delimited `string` that is then wrapped in an `(i)stringstream` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `std::istream` is inherently character-based. If you want to keep using `callMe(std::istream& is)` as an interface, you are bound to convert every element of `myVector` to characters and back at some point. If you want to stick with this option, I personally find `ostream_iterator` an elegant solution:

```cpp
copy(begin(data), end(data), std::ostream_iterator<float>(sstr));
```

Full example:

```cpp
void callMeStream(std::istream &is)
{
  float f1;
  is >> f1;
  std::cout << "Stream: " << f1 << std::endl;
}

// ...

std::vector<float> data = {3.5, 1.5, 2.5 /* ... */};

std::stringstream sstr;
copy(begin(data), end(data), std::ostream_iterator<float>(sstr));
callMeStream(sstr); // Output: "Stream: 3.51"
```

If you are willing to change the signature of `callMe`, this conversion can be avoided:

```cpp
template <class T>
void callMeTemplate(T &is)
{
  float f1;
  is >> f1;
  std::cout << "Template: " << f1 << std::endl;
}

#define NO_ELEMENT -1.0;

class data_wrapper
{
  std::vector<float>::const_iterator current;
  const std::vector<float>::const_iterator last;

public:
  data_wrapper(const std::vector<float> &data) : current(begin(data)), last(end(data)) {}

  data_wrapper &operator>>(float &value)
  {
    if (last == current)
    {
      value = NO_ELEMENT;
    }
    else
    {
      value = *current++;
    }
    return *this;
  }
};

// ...
data_wrapper wrapper(data);
callMeTemplate(wrapper); // Output: "Template: 3.5"
```

In the second example, the `float` value never gets converted to a character sequence, and could accept both `data_wrapper` and `std::istream` types. Of course, if you are willing to change the signature of `callMe` entirely, you might as well change it to accept a begin/end iterator range or a `vector` directly.